# ORM/ADO.NET data services for asp.net-mvc web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, ado.net

As i am a beginner to asp.net-mvc which should i use ORM/ADO.NET data services.... As far as i see all the examples are only with ORM support.... So experts please guide me on this...

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you looking for a .NET ORM recommendation or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is strange.

You use Ado.net Data Services, now WCF Data Services, with an Entity Framework, which is an ORM itself.    ;)

Using a straight ORM vs abstraction over WCF Data Services is largely based on the physical tiering of your servers.   If your webserver cannot connect to your database server or you you need tiered architecture for multi-tenancy/security/scaling reasons than you need to use a web service technology like WCF or WCF Data Services.

You'll probably be fine with an ORM like NHIbernate, Entity Framework, Lightspeed, Subsonic, or whichever new one comes out.

Answer (score -2):

[S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.com)

OK, maybe [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx) is better. Look at "Why use ORM" there.